# Limit of an integral related to characteristic functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with CDF $F_X$ and characteristic function $\varphi_X(t) = Ee^{itX}$. The inversion formula for the characteristic function gives:
$$
F_X(b)-F_X(a)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \lim _{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-T}^{+T} \frac{e^{-i t a}-e^{-i t b}}{i t} \varphi_X(t) d t .
$$
Here $a$ and $b$ must be in the continuity set of $F_X$. I'm interested to show using this formula that
$$
P(|X| \le c) \to 1, \mbox{ as } c \to \infty.  
$$

In the simple case where $X=0$, so $\varphi_X(t) = 1$, and using that $e^{ i t c}-e^{-i t c} = 2i \sin(tc),$ we see this is equivalent to the statement
$$
\lim_{c\to \infty} \frac{1}{  \pi} \lim _{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-T}^{+T} \frac{  \sin(tc)}{ t}   d t  =1.
$$
Why is this true? Why in general does

$$
\lim_{c\to \infty} \frac{1}{  \pi} \lim _{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-T}^{+T} \frac{  \sin(tc)}{ t}  \varphi_X(t) d t  =1?
$$

I assume this should have to do with the fact that $\varphi_X(t)$ is close to one in modulus near zero, but I cannot see why other than to reverse engineer the inversion formula and use continuity of the probability measure.

Comment: So you want to prove the last equation directly?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal! Even I would appreciate if someone could illuminate the case where $\varphi_X = 1$, since this is just a calculus question, although does not appear trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the substiution $u\gets ct$ in your integral and the fact that $\varphi(0)=1$ and of course at the end use [Dirichlet integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral).

Comment: Thank you! I will work out the details, but I was not aware of the Dirichlet integral! Looks promising

Comment: You are welcome! And good luck for fixing all the details.